# White space + margins + alignment problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, vertical-alignment, margins, white-space

I'm using overleaf to write my thesis but I found two problems in the template as illustrated in the attached image.
1- Long white space at the beginning of main pages (abstract, declaration, dedication, acknowledgment,...).
2- The margin changes in all pages "1st page like 3rd page, 2nd page like 4th page), not all pages have the same alignment.
[image]

Comment: (1) You can change this, but one would need to know what class/packages you're using to set the chapters. (2) This is because of using the `twoside` option for your class. Change it to `oneside` to avoid this shifting of margin.

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,leqno,openbib]{memoir}

Comment: I can share the main code. It is available through an overleaf template.

Comment: Sure thing. Share away!

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-technology-sydney-uts-thesis-template/kndxjkgqmnjj

Answer (score -1):

In preamble, add \topmargin=-2cm . This you can adjust.
To have same page style, use \newpage when the odd side page ends. Please see whether it works.